# Click-though Image Gallery (prev/next) with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gallery

I'm a newbie looking for help.
What I want to do is this:

I have about nine projects listed on my home page each with a large image. Each project has about five other unshown images.

I'm trying to figure out how to click on the main image and have it load the next image in its place, staying on the same page, no transition needed. I have text links to the side to also control 'next' or 'previous' images if you click on them.

I'd like the images (aside from the nine initial) to load as you need them, so I'm not loading 50 images right from the start.

I'ts also been a headache trying to make nine independent gallery/slideshows on the same page.

Right now, I'm using a bloated, messy javascript that I hacked together rto get it done, but its unstable across browsers and I feel like it has a LOT of unnecessary code. So I won't bother posting it, I think I need to start from scratch.

I feel like this should be relatively simple but I can't find any plugins or examples anywhere that do this simple task.

I'm a total amateur, but I'd love to learn how to actually code it, so if anyone knows of any tutorials out there that could help me, I would really appreciate it! I have in my head that it should just be some simple jQuery, but I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I feel there's no reason to reinvent the wheel, just use this http://nivogallery.dev7studios.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you must reinvent the wheel, here is a bare bones simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KDnPX/

Html:

```
<img src="">
    <a href="#" class="prevImg">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="nextImg">Next</a>
```

Jquery:

```
var json = '{"0":"http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/14748463.jpg", 
"1":"http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/3840183.jpg", 
"2":"http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/25214140.jpg"}';

var images = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

// load first image
$('img').attr('src', images[0]);

var currImg = 0;

$('.prevImg').click(function (){
    if (currImg - 1 >= 0)
    {
        // show previous image
        $('img').attr('src', images[currImg - 1]);
        currImg--;
    }
    return false;
});

$('.nextImg').click(function (){
    if (currImg + 1 < Object.keys(images).length)
    {
        // show previous image
        $('img').attr('src', images[currImg + 1]);
        currImg++;
    }
    return false;
});
```